# Fit part of the ellipse

Tags: matlab

I have an ellipse given by these coordinates.

```
etta=0:pi/100:2*pi;
coord(1,:)=a*cos(etta)+sqrt(a^2-b^2);
coord(2,:)=b*sin(etta);
```

Then I select a point on the ellipse whose coordinates are (x1,y1).

How can a find the nearest points to this point, make a curve with those points, and then do a polyfit.

I encountered some difficulties, because for one x, we have two y's in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your answers are maybe obvious, so I try to point out the key concepts and leave implementation to you.

to "How can a find the nearest points to this point":

- calculate the distance of the points and choose the ones below some treshold you set

to "because for one x, we have two y's in this case"

- obviously x or y are "bad" choices for a parameter. Introduce a new one that is unique - maybe the order of points. (read [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation) for inspiration)
- if you need y as function of x - you can do it by solving to t in the x equation and putting it into the formula for y.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, but I already solved a problem. They weren't that obvious though. The one point here is that I can't use any other parameter, because I have [x,y] starting point.